# Ordering an array by value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this array :

```
a = [{'id': 1, 'date: '2020-01-31'}, {'id': 2, 'date': '2020-01-25'}, {'id': 3, 'date': '2020-01-26'}]
```

I would like to order it by date like that :

```
a = [{'id': 2, 'date': '2020-01-25'}, {'id': 3, 'date': '2020-01-26'}, {'id': 3, 'date'; '2020-01-31'}]
```

How can I do this to sort my array like that ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a list of dictionaries by a value of the dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-a-value-of-the-dictionary)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest solution: use the built-in `sorted` function, and for the `key` default argument, use a `lambda` expression to extract the date of each element, as shown below:

```py
a = [
    {'id': 1, 'date': '2020-01-31'},
    {'id': 2, 'date': '2020-01-25'},
    {'id': 3, 'date': '2020-01-26'}
]

a_sorted = sorted(a, key=lambda e: e['date'])

print(a_sorted)
```

Console output:

```
[{'id': 2, 'date': '2020-01-25'}, {'id': 3, 'date': '2020-01-26'}, {'id': 1, 'date': '2020-01-31'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort the array on your own, you can use a sorting Algorithm, for example the [bubble sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/) or you can check here in this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-algorithms/) for more algorithms

Answer (score 0):

sorted(a, key= lambda item: item['date'])

if you need descending order

sorted(a, key= lambda item: item['date'], reverse=True)